# Nginx server_name - Site Regular Expression - Matching Multiple sites

Tags: regex, nginx

I'm trying to match the following URL's with an Nginx server_name. Eg: the second part needs to match via wildcard.

```
websocket.etc1.africa.dating
websocket.etc2.africa.dating
```

I've tried regular expressions like:

```
server_name ~^websocket\d+\.africa\.dating$
server_name ~^websocket\..+\.africa\.dating$
```

I've also tried in double quotes and without.

Any advise on how to match these URL's with a changing second part.

thanks
Adam

Comment: Do you have a semicolon in each end of `server_name` statement?  `server_name ~^websocket\d+\.africa\.dating$;`  `sudo nginx -t` would warn about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`server_name ~^websocket\d+\.africa\.dating$` would only match URLs like (notice no `.` between "websocket" and "123")

- websocket123.africa.dating

`server_name ~^websocket\..+\.africa\.dating$` would only match URLs like

- websocket.....africa.dating

What you need is probably

```
server_name ~^websocket\.[a-z0-9]+\.africa\.dating$
```

or

```
server_name ~^websocket\.\w+\.africa\.dating$
```